# Where is the main method in apache tomcat 9?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

I want to modify apache tomcat9 for my goals so I want to know where the start point of the program as main method?

Comment: Are you asking us to grep the source code for you?

Comment: no I can not find location

Comment: I can't imagine any project where modifying tomcat is the solution (apart from developing Tomcat further or debugging it). Sounds like a [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) to me, e.g. finding the answer to _this_ question is unlikely solving your _underlying_ problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the tip is to use [`jps`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/jps.html) (A CLI tool shipped with Java SDK) to print out the main method that start a Java Process after you start Tomcat. You have to use `-l` if you want to display full patch of the main method and `-m` to display the arguments passed to the main method :

```sh
jps -lmv
```

Then it will show something like :

```sh
6622 org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/kc/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -Dcatalina.base=/Users/kc/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.8 -Dcatalina.home=/Users/kc/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Users/kc/Downloads/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/temp
```

which means the main method that start Tomcat is the class [`org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/81e721526d4125e68e591dddf14dbb460f02f43b/java/org/apache/catalina/startup/Bootstrap.java#L436)